# Linq - Updating all the properties but not the key one

Tags: linq, oop, reflection, entity-framework-4

I've an 'product' object that has to update a record in db.
Through a 'productCode' I retrieve the object to update using Linq.
Which is the most elegant way to overwrite alle the property but not the key one and then save changes?

Comment: Any code samples to make it clear.

Comment: AutoMapper is great for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access each property anyways, as you fetch a record manually. my recommendation for easiest, fastest and cleanest code:

```
code = productCode_toChange
using(Entity ent = new Entity())
{
var update = (from x in ent.Products where x.productCode == code select x).First();
update.property1 = product.property1;
update.property2 = product.property2;
// and so on for each property you change
ent.SaveChanges();
}
```

you could of course try:

```
using(Entity ent = new Entity())
{  
var update = (from x in ent.Products where x.productCode == code select x).First();
update = product;
ent.SaveChanges();
}
```

but i can almost guarantee this will not work, as product will certainly have an id-property it will try to write to update, which will throw an exception, given the case product is the LINQ-generated type for the table-instance.

Be careful to check for type-conformity. also note, that you the SQL-Type of product code should not be text, as this type is incomparable